# What's the advantage of binding a base class to a derived class as opposed to simply creating a derived class pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, polymorphism

Notice in this example I created a derived class pointer (Laser* pLaser = new Laser) instead of a base class pointer like (Boat* pLaser = new Laser). Is there an advantage creating a base class pointer instead? Thanks!

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Boat      
    {
        protected:
         int length;

        public:
         int getLength() { return length; }
         virtual void Model() = 0;
    };

    class Sailboat : public Boat        
    {
        protected:
         int mast;

        public:
         int getMast() { return mast; }
         virtual void Boom() = 0;
    };

    class Laser : public Sailboat       
    {
        public:
         Laser() { mast = 19; length = 35; }    
         ~Laser();                              

         void Model() { cout << "Laser Classic" << endl; }  
         void Boom() { cout << "Boom: 14 ft" << endl; }
    };


    int main()
    {
        Laser* pLaser = new Laser;      

        pLaser -> Model();
        cout << "Length: " << pLaser -> getLength() << "ft" << endl;
        cout << "Height: " << pLaser -> getMast() << "ft" << endl;
        pLaser -> Boom();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The `Base b = Derived` (notice the implitit casting) technique may be useful when you need to store several pointers, all of them pointing to Base-derived classes instances. I cannot think of a useful case for creating `Base b = new Derived()`

Comment: Well, if you assign the result of the `new` to a base class pointer, you will not be able to `delete` it without triggering undefined behavior. For extra credit you can figure out why, and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the input! makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one have a different purpose.

### Child pointer

`Laser* pLaser = new Laser` purpose is to simply use dynamic allocation for this type, sometimes for sharing this data with other threads/processes. Usually you don't have to use it in C++, and you usually allocate this type on the stack.

### Parent pointer

`Boat* pLaser = new Laser` This is a different story of polymorphism. If you want to store different type that implement the same interface you *have* to use this form (usually with smart pointers, but still same idea). For example, assume you want a container (e.g. `std::vector`) to include both `Sailboat` and `Laser`. Using this form you can do something like:

```
std::vector<Boat*> vec = {new Laser(), new Sailboat()};
for (auto &e : vec) {
    std::cout << e->getLength() << std::endl; 
}
```

As I mentioned, sometimes you have to use this form, and those times are when you have at lease one pure virtual function in you base class. In this case, you can't create an object on the stack of the base class (due to incomplete type). For exmaple:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual int compare(int, int) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int compare(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }
};

int main() {
    //Base b; // Compilation error
    Derived c; // OK
    std::shared_ptr<Base> base_pointer = std::make_shared<Derived>(); // OK
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Read more about:

[Polymorphism C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-c/)